# Only allowing certain Java apps through firewall

Tags: firewall, java, windows-firewall

Using Windows Firewall and Advanced Security, I block everything outgoing by default and define outgoing rules to allow my approved apps through.

For Java apps, I only allow java.exe through to specific IPs.

However this is getting to be a bit unmanageable as I'm running more and more Java apps, especially when external IPs change.

I don't particularly wish to just allow java.exe through on any port or IP.

Is there any way I can only allow certain .jar files run under the Java VM through?

Or some other strategy?